# What is the defacto way to tell a page to focus an element via anchor?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, anchor

I have a routable React component that can be linked to from a few different places, some of which are React, some of which are Marionette (which we are in the process of phasing out).

Some of the links will need to automatically focus an input element in that React component, but again, I will be linking outside of React as well, so I can't pass a prop.

Is there a good way to have the link itself be what tells the React component to focus something? My intuition is to use document.location.search and have that read in the component, but I didn't know if anyone could think of a better way.  I'd like to not add something to the URL if possible. Thanks!

Comment: The `#` fragment identifier is for indicating what element to make visible as close to the top of the viewport as possible. Perhaps you could use that as the `id` of the element to focus when routing within your application.

Comment: Unfortunately we use # for routing instead of pushState for our SPA. Historically speaking it's because we used to support IE7, but # is a no-go in my situation